# Python Qt4 classes printout

Tags: python, class, pyqt, qt4

I have a QT4 MainWindow for the graphical part.
Then a base class.
Any derived classes from base class (only one in the example).
I would like to print the info in the base class followed by the info of one of the derived classes (depends on the situation) on the same window.

My code result now, is that, I see only the result of the derived class on the window, because the result of the base class are probably printed out on a window that immediatly desappear to print out the new window of the derived class.

Can you help me?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.resize(750, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle("TEST")

        self.printTest1(10, 20, 30, 40)

# BASE CLASS
class test1(self):                        # Inherit from MainWindow
    a=0
    b=0
    c=0
    d=0

    # PRINT BASE CLASS
    def printTest1(self, a, b, c, d):       # Inherit from test1
        self.printA=a
        self.printB=b
        self.printC=c
        self.printD=d

        cWidget = QtGui.QWidget()

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(cWidget)

        vBox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        etichetta1 = QtGui.QLabel("A: " + str(self.printA), cWidget)
        etichetta2 = QtGui.QLabel("B: " + str(self.printB), cWidget)
        etichetta3 = QtGui.QLabel("C: " + str(self.printC), cWidget)
        etichetta4 = QtGui.QLabel("D: " + str(self.printD), cWidget)
        vBox.addWidget(etichetta1)
        vBox.addWidget(etichetta2)
        vBox.addWidget(etichetta3)
        vBox.addWidget(etichetta4)

        grid.addLayout(vBox, 1, 0)

        cWidget.setLayout(grid)
        self.setCentralWidget(cWidget)

        self.printTest2(100, 200)

# DERIVED CLASS FROM BASE CLASS
class printTest2(self, a1, b1):           # Inherit from test1
    self.printA1=a1
    self.printB1=b1

    cWidget = QtGui.QWidget()

    grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(cWidget)

    vBox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    etichetta1 = QtGui.QLabel("A1: " + str(self.printA1), cWidget)
    etichetta2 = QtGui.QLabel("B1: " + str(self.printB1) , cWidget)
    vBox.addWidget(etichetta1)
    vBox.addWidget(etichetta2)

    grid.addLayout(vBox, 1, 0)

    cWidget.setLayout(grid)
    self.setCentralWidget(cWidget)

a=test1()
a.printTest1(10, 20, 30, 40)

app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
main=MainWindow()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `test1`, `printTest1` and `printTest2` are not classes, they are methods from the same class `MainWindow`.

Comment: yes, you're right.         But should be: test1 Base class, printTest1 & printTest2 methods of class test1

Comment: `test1` is still not a class, or maybe you need to edit your code. Anyway I think your problem is that you redefine a central widget from scratch in printTest 1 and 2. If you call printTest2 after printTest1, you don't add labels to `cWidget`. Instead you create a new `cWidget`, so you don't see what you defined in printTest1.